# Not getting what's happening in the JavaScript script code below

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, es6-promise

```js
async function async1(){
  console.log(1)
  await async2()
  console.log(2)
}

async function async2(){
  console.log(3)
}

console.log(4)

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log(5)
}, 0)

async1()

new Promise(function(resolve){
  console.log(6)
  resolve()
}).then(function(){
  console.log(7)
})

console.log(8)
```

```
4
1
3
6
8
7
2
5
```

Please explain how this code creating the above output. I'm confused with Why the 2 not come immediately after log(3). what is exactly happening after we use async await ?.
please provide some insights on this.

Comment: With `await` you are yielding execution, returning to the event loop, and therefore other queued tasks have a chance to run before your code continues.

Comment: Do you understand why `7` does not print immediately after `6`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not doing `await` on async1 method invocation (async1()), The control will be on current execution context and console.log(2) will be moved to `micro task queue` in event loop.

Please execute your code again with changing `await async2()` in browser console and you will notice the expected order.

[image]

Update: Adding more details

The `async` functions return the promise.
When using `await` for async function execution means, the rest of code after the await will be executed after the async promise resolve.

To see the execution flow, I have converted to equivalent code which using directly promises.

```js
console.log(4);

setTimeout(function () { // move to call back queue
  console.log(5);
}, 0);

new Promise(function () {
  console.log(1);
  new Promise(function (resolve) {
    console.log(3);
    resolve();
  }).then(function () { // move to micro task queue
    console.log(2);
  });
});

new Promise(function (resolve) {
  console.log(6);
  resolve();
}).then(function () { // move to micro task queue
  console.log(7);
});

console.log(8);
```

Comment: then how log(1) prints?. Could you please explain the flow from beginning

Comment: @pranavm, updated the answer with more details.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, while execute the code, i get a output as : 4
1
3
6
8
2
7
5  where as in orginal 2 come after 7. why its so? @siva-k-v